# c# IVMRWindowlessControl9 query failed

Tags: c#, winapi, video, directshow, directshow.net

Why I can do something like this without any problem
`((IVMRFilterConfig9)pVideoMixingRenderer1).SetRenderingMode(VMR9Mode.Windowless);`

but when I try this

```
IVMRWindowlessControl9 vc1 = (IVMRWindowlessControl9)pVideoMixingRenderer1;
```

i have invalid cast exception ( HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))?

The VMR9 renderer itself is working just fine btw.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is accurately documented. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390537):

> The VMR-9 supports this interface in windowless and renderless modes only. In windowed mode, `QueryInterface` returns `E_NOINTERFACE`.

You're showing a line which supposedly switches to windowless mode, but this has its own limitations. When in windowless mode, the interface would be available.

DirectShow.NET samples offer a few with `IVMRWindowlessControl9` use, you can check them out for proper interface use.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It looks like you have to add renderers to your graph without connecting them, then turn on windowless mode to get access to windowlesscontrol. Then you have to set windowlesscontrol parameters and when all of this is done the input pins of renderers can be connected. I was trying to do it in wrong order and that was my biggest mistake.